# Using Express.js modules in Sails.js

Tags: sqlite, express, sails.js

Sails.js does not yet have official Sqlite adapter. There are some attempts, but having read the comments, they are buggy and not reliable.

Since Sails.js uses Express.js, and Express has decent sqlite modules, I was thinking how to use it in Sails?

Any idea is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to do it. Very easy. First Install the [sql3lite package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sqlite3#installing)

Lets Assume I have UserController. At the start of the controller, use this:

```
sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose(),
db = new sqlite3.Database('myDbName');
```

db object has all that is needed. You can check the link for detailed CRUD reference :)